# Next Full Release Date of ASP.NET MVC (MVC 1.1 / 1.5 / 2.0 anyone?)

Tags: model-view-controller, version

Does anybody have an idea when the next version of ASP.NET MVC is scheduled for release?

The Futures assembly has many features that are important (Asynchronous Controllers, invoke partial actions etc.), but I don't want to use beta/futures code in a production website - so, does anybody have an idea when the next version is about to come out?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net MVC 2 will shiped with Visual Studio 2010.

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/30/asp.net-mvc-released.aspx

There is no fixed date for that, but I think that it is first half of 2010.

Answer (score 2):

April 12th (as of Jan 29th 2010)
[link text](http://www.internetnews.com/software/article.php/3858841/Microsoft+Confirms+Visual+Studio+2010+Ship+Date.htm)

Answer (score 0):

No idea, but you can get hints from the codeplex site if you pay close attention to checkins.

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/